# LWC: Assertion error when testing @wire chain in Jest

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest, wire

I am trying to write Jest test for a component with two `@wired` calls (both bound to functions), but I get assertion error about property of second `@wire` call not being annotated with wire annotation.
`Error: Assert Violation: @wire on "handlePicklistResult": dot-notation reactive parameter "accountObjectInfo.defaultRecordTypeId" must refer to a @wire property`

Any suggestions?

Here is sample code that I am trying to test:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Type';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';


export default class Democomponent extends LightningElement {
    @track accountObjectInfo;
    @track error;
    @track picklistValues;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    handleResult({error, data}) {
        if(data) {
            this.accountObjectInfo = data;
        } else {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {recordTypeId: "$accountObjectInfo.defaultRecordTypeId", fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD})
    handlePicklistResult({error, data}) {
        if(data) {
            this.picklistValues = data.values;
        } else {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

}
```

Simple test I want to perform:

```
import {registerLdsTestWireAdapter} from '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest';
import {createElement} from 'lwc';
import {getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues} from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import TestPage from 'c/testPage';

const mockGetObjectInfo = require('./data/getObjectInfo.json');
const mockGetPicklistValues = require('./data/getPicklistValues.json');

const getObjectInfoAdapter = registerLdsTestWireAdapter(getObjectInfo);
const getPicklistValuesAdapter = registerLdsTestWireAdapter(getPicklistValues);

describe('c-test-page', () => {

    it('Should display test page', () => {
        const element = createElement('c-test-page', {
            is: TestPage
        });

        document.body.appendChild(element);

        getObjectInfoAdapter.emit(mockGetObjectInfo);
        getPicklistValuesAdapter.emit(mockGetPicklistValues);

        const picklistItems = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('div.picklistItem');

        expect(picklistItems.length).toEqual(5);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this code and it is working for me.

Comment: The code itself works, but lwc-jest complains and throws the error as stated in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, please add the test code as well.

Comment: I have added test code.

Comment: @DavidReed Were you able to replicate this error? I'm unable to & this code works just fine for me. This could have been an issue from the past which has been already fixed in LWC. So, unless '@ceez' updates the code snippets (to help replicate this issue), I'm not sure if further troubleshooting can be done for this problem.

Comment: One quick thing to check is being sure to always declare a variable that's intended to be used as an object (or array) as such. So you could just try making this change in the declaration and see if that helps: `@track accountObjectInfo = {};`

Likewise with the picklist array: `@track picklistValues = [];`

Comment: Can you tell us which version of `sfdx-lwc-jest` you're running? Latest at time of writing is v0.10.2 for testing under api v50.0.

Comment: @arut No, I didn't repro the error, but someone on one of my teams is struggling with a similar error.

Comment: @DavidReed Could you ask them to post the replication steps (_or any additional details_) here or in a new post?

Answer (score 3):

There are several things that you need to correct in your test.

The most important one is that you don't need to fire both wires if you're just testing for the state of the template.
Firing the `getObjectInfo` wire is not needed for this test because the test doesn't use the value of the `recordTypeId` parameter in the `getPicklistValues` test wire.

Then, you need to wait for the component to re-render after emitting data through the wire. We generally use a `Promises.resolve()` call to do that (see [LWC Recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/wireGetPicklistValues/__tests__/wireGetPicklistValues.test.js#L34)).

Also, don't test with a hardcoded item length: `expect(picklistItems.length).toEqual(5);`. Use a dynamic value from your mock data instead: `expect(picklistItems.length).toBe(mockGetPicklistValues.values.length);`.

Here's the updated test that passes:

```js
describe("c-test-page", () => {
  it("Should display test page", () => {
    const element = createElement("c-test-page", {
      is: TestPage
    });
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    getPicklistValuesAdapter.emit(mockGetPicklistValues);

    // Return a promise to wait for any asynchronous DOM updates. Jest
    // will automatically wait for the Promise chain to complete before
    // ending the test and fail the test if the promise rejects.
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      const picklistItems = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(
        ".picklistItem"
      );
      expect(picklistItems.length).toBe(mockGetPicklistValues.values.length);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: While all points in you answer are correct, were you able to replicate the original error posted in the question? I couldn't. The error message doesn't make any sense to me in the test JS (since, it will be using mock adapters).

Comment: No, I couldn't reproduce the error but it could be that @ceez is using a different version of sfdx-lwc-jest. I'm on the latest version (v0.10.2 for testing api v50.0).

Comment: I felt that same must be the case. I'm on sfdx-lwc-jest v0.7.1. So, this may have been an issue with a much older version

Comment: Not necessarily and older version, it could also be a regression introduced later.